# display information using django tags

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am writing a site on Django, the purpose of this site is to create a test to assess students' knowledge

I need help with outputting options for answers to a question

I keep the questions in a list and the answer options in a nested list
for example:

questions = [ "question1","question2","question3"]

answers = [[ "answer1","answer2",answer3 ],["answer1","answer2",answer3,answer4 ] ,
["answer1","answer2",answer3 ]]`

and I need this data to be displayed in the following format:

```
question1  
   answer1
   answer2
   answer3

question2  
   answer1  
   answer2  
   answer3  
   answer4 

question3  
   answer1  
   answer2  
   answer3
```

here is my code, it does not work very correctly, I know, I have not yet figured out how to implement it in Django tags

```
 {% for question in questions %}
            <p>{{question}}</p>
            <ul>
                {% for answer in answers %}

                    {% for current in answer %}

                      <li><input type="radio" id="option{{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="answer{{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}" value="{{ current }}">{{ current }}</li>

                    {% endfor %}

                {% endfor %}    
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Share the view, Please format your code properly. [edit] your code, select the code fragments and click on the "Code sample" button (`{}`) to format the code.

Comment: Your data structures aren't suited well for your usecase. A list of dictionaries like `[{"question": "Question 1", "answers": ["Answer 1"]}]` might be a better choice. Even a list of tuples with a question as one element and answer as others would be a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform the joining in the *view*:

```
def my_view(request):
    questions = ['question1', 'question2', 'question3']
    answers = [
        ['answer11', 'answer12', 'answer13'],
        ['answer21', 'answer22', 'answer23', 'answer24'],
        ['answer31', 'answer32', 'answer33'],
    ]
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'qas': zip(questions, answers)})
```

and in the template work with:

```
{% for question, answers in qas %}
  <p>{{question}}</p>
  <ul>
  {% for answer in answers %}
    <li><input type="radio" id="option{{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="answer{{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}" value="{{ current }}">{{ current }}</li>
  {% endfor %}    
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

That being said, what you do is [*primitive obsession* <sup>[refactoring.guru]</sup>](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession): expressing data in terms of lists, strings, etc. If data has a certain structure, it makes more sense to define a dedicated class for it, and add logic to it. For example to render the `id=""` for the option, and logic to parse back data.

Answer (score -1):

```
{% for question, answer_list in zip(questions, answers) %}
{{ question }}
<ul>
    {% for answer in answer_list %}
        <li>{{ answer }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

{% endfor %}

It's just a variant

Comment: This won't work in a Django template, I think you're answering for Jinja templates.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).